# Files from website's directory not displyed in google search results

Tags: operator-keyword, file-type

I know the website(say **xyz.com**)
 which have some **.zip** files (say **xyz.com/y0.zip**) but *they haven't specified on website* they just uploaded it(saved in their storage).
I know some file's name (here **y0.zip or y1.zip**)
and I don't know some file's name(say **n.zip**)

after long googling i.e. searching **filetype:zip site:xyz.com** 
and also  **"www.xyz.com/y0.zip"**

still I AM NOT GETTING ANY RESULT from google search

I **want list of zip files in google results**  so that I will be able to download unknown files (here **n.zip**)

Is there any operators in google search or any other ways to achieve it..

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that Google has indexed this file?

Comment: www.xyz.com/y0.zip is working when I put it into address bar...But google is not showing any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Google` and other search engines index files by exploring all the web pages in the website.

the exploring usually starts from the main (index) page, and spread to other webpages that is reachable (i.e. linked) from this page, the same operation is done to all discovered pages.

so if there is no links in webpages(on the same website or any other one) that is linking to the .zip files you are asking about, search engine will not be able to discover those files.

also some websites have `robots.txt` file that contains a list of directories, to tell the search engine that is exploring the site, to do **NOT** explore those directories and any sub ones or files, such directories contains administration and private content.

Comment: Right....but I am able to download **www.xyz.com/y0.zip** , so if these files exists there, I should somehow reach there via search engine or other sources..

Comment: @YesMan so how search engine will know that these files exists?